# How could I keep the ratio of images on Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: php, html, css, firefox

I used this code to retrieve and keep the ratio of an image:

```
<img class="r r-2x img-full " style="background:url('<?php echo $image; ?>') no-repeat top center; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover;  background-size: cover;"/>
```

this solution works in IE and Chrome not in Mozilla Firefox where the image is not displayed. So how could I proceed? I tried with `src="<?php echo $image; ?>"`, but the ratio is not respected

Comment: Why use an `<img>` tag, when setting just the background image? Either use an `<img>` tag with its `src` attribute or just a `<div>` container.

Comment: This is the answer! Thank you so much, I just changed the `img` to `div` and now it works! ;)

Comment: hmm. i can not explain why a div works here, while a img does not. so this would not be an answer imo.

Comment: @Sirko Me too, but finally it works! That background it's inside a `figure` tag...it could be something related it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `img` or `div` shouldn't matter.
The only problem I see is that I have to apply a width and height on the element in order to view the image. The image stays in the correct aspect ratio though.

**With the img tag:**

```
<img class="r-r-2x-img-full" border="0" style="display:block; width: 100px; height: auto; background:url('<?php echo $image; ?>') no-repeat top center; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover;  background-size: cover;" />
```

**With the div tag:**

```
<div class="r-r-2x-img-full" border="0" style="display:block; width: 100px; height: auto; background:url('<?php echo $image; ?>') no-repeat top center; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover;  background-size: cover;" />
```

Hope this helped you out :)